# How to access the currently iterated array value in a loop?

Tags: javascript

***Current attempt using an array of objects with properties:***

The objective:

I want to automatically fill out emails on behalf of ~30 different people. The form fields are always consistent, but the values I'm filling in will change on an email-to-email basis. I'm using TagUI to do this.

My old code (last code box below) successfully filled out each form by assigning each line [in the .csv](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16iF7F-8eh2eE6kDiye0GVlmOCjADQjlVE9W1KH0Y8MM/edit?usp=sharing) to a separate array BUT failed to iterate through the values of a specific column within the .csv. Please see the text above the last code box below for further explanation.

Now I'm starting again, this time aiming to create an array of objects (representing each email being sent) with properties (representing each field to be filled within each email).

Here's what I've got so far:

```
// Using TagUI for browser automation
// https://github.com/kelaberetiv/TagUI
website-to-automate-URL-here.com

// Set up the arrays to be used later
emails = []

// Load in the 'db.csv' file
// Link to .csv: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16iF7F-8eh2eE6kDiye0GVlmOCjADQjlVE9W1KH0Y8MM/edit?usp=sharing
csv_file = 'db.csv'
load '+csv_file+' to csv_lines

// Split the string variable "lines" into an array of individual lines
lines = csv_lines.split('\n')

// Split the individual lines up into individual properties
for (i=0; i < lines.length; i++)
{
emails[i].name = properties[1].trim()
emails[i].recipients = properties[2].trim()    
properties = lines[i].split(',')



}
```

EDIT: The **below** code has been put on the back burner as I attempt to solve this another way. Solutions are still welcome.

I'm having trouble triggering my for loop (the last one in the code below).

My goal for the for loop in question, in plain English, is as follows: Repeat the below code X times, where X is determined by the current iteration of the total_images array.

So if the total_images array looks like this:

```
[Total Images, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

And the parent for loop is on its third iteration, then this for loop should dictate that the following code is executed 4 times.

I'm using TagUI (https://github.com/kelaberetiv/TagUI), so there many be some non-Javascript code here.

```
https://www.website.com
wait 3s

// Setting up all the arrays that the .csv will load

array_campaign = []
array_subject = []
array_teaser = []
array_recipients = []
array_exclude = []

array_img1src = []
array_img1alt = []
array_img1url = []

array_img2src = []
array_img2alt = []
array_img2url = []

array_img3src = []
array_img3alt = []
array_img3url = []

array_img4src = []
array_img4alt = []
array_img4url = []

total_images = []

// Load in the 'db.csv' file
csv_file = 'db.csv'
load '+csv_file+' to lines

// Chop up the .csv data into individual pieces
// NOTE: Make sure the [#] corresponds to .csv column
// Reminder: Numbers start at 0
array_lines = lines.split('\n')
for (n=0; n<array_lines.length; n++)
{
  items = array_lines[n].split(',')
  array_campaign[n] = items[1].trim()
  array_recipients[n] = items[2].trim()
  array_exclude[n] = items[3].trim()
  array_subject[n] = items[4].trim()
  array_teaser[n] = items[5].trim()
  array_img1src[n] = items[6].trim()
  array_img1alt[n] = items[7].trim()
  array_img1url[n] = items[8].trim()
  array_img2src[n] = items[9].trim()
  array_img2alt[n] = items[10].trim()
  array_img2url[n] = items[11].trim()
  array_img3src[n] = items[12].trim()
  array_img3alt[n] = items[13].trim()
  array_img3url[n] = items[14].trim()
  array_img4src[n] = items[15].trim()
  array_img4alt[n] = items[16].trim()
  array_img4url[n] = items[17].trim()
  total_images[n] = items[18].trim()
}

for (i=1; i < array_campaign.length; i++)
{
echo "This is a campaign entry."
wait 2s
}


// This is the problem loop that's being skipped

blocks = total_images[i]
for (image_blocks=0; image_blocks < blocks; image_blocks++)
{
hover vis1_3.png
click visClone.png
}
```

This is the most coding I've ever done, so if you could point me in the right direction and explain like I'm a beginner it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try using an array consisting of objects with properties for each csv column, instead of having one array for each column. That'll make it much simpler. Also use an array for the image.

Comment: @Bergi This makes sense, thank you. I'm keeping a list of optimizations/improvements to make once I'm able to solve this last problem and hack together a "good enough" working solution.

Comment: @Bergi I'm now attempting to solve this using your suggestion. I've put my current best (but flawed) attempt at the top of the post. I've also been reading about "forEach" but I'm not 100% sure if it's the answer. Any guidance would be MUCH appreciated. Also included link to .csv/Google Doc in code comments.

Comment: You'd have to start the loop body with `emails[i] = {}`, before assigning properties to that object.

Comment: Made the adjustment but receive this: `ERROR - can't find variable: properties`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My old code should have worked. I opened up the .csv file in notepad and noticed there were SEVERAL extra commas interfering with the last column of data, throwing everything for a loop.

Did some searching and apparently this is a common thing. Beware!

Answer (score 0):

Look like the only reason make your last loop being skipped is that `total_images[i]` is `undefined`, which is used for the loop condition. I believe that the value of `i` at that moment is equal to `array_campaign.length` from the previous loop, which is actually out of array range.

Here're some example codes:

```
const arr = [0, 1, 2];
const length = arr.length; // the length is 3, but the last index of this array is 2 (count from 0)

for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  console.log(i);
}

// output:
// 0
// 1
// 2

console.log(i); // i at this moment is 3, which is = arr.length and made the above loop exit

console.log(arr[i]); // => undefined, because the last index of the above array is 2, so if you reference to an un-existed element of an array, it will return undefined.
```

"run the following code X times, where X is determined by the value of total_images[i]" - so, if I understand your question correctly, you can use nested loops to do this:

```
for (i=1; i < array_campaign.length; i++)
{
  echo "This is a campaign entry."
  wait 2s

  // nested loop, the number of iteration is based on the value i of outside loop
  for (j=0; j < total_images[i]; j++) {
    // do something here
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to say "run the following code X times, where X is determined by the value of total_images[i]" _inside the previous for statement_ to stay in range?

Comment: Yes, this is the objective! Unfortunately the nested for loop was skipped again. I've tried more or less the same thing and it's still being skipped.

Comment: Could you check again data in `total_images`. Follow your code, I'm afraid that it's an array of string: `total_images[n] = items[18].trim()`, which will make the evaluation of for loop fail, because we're comparing a number with a string.

Comment: I just removed that line `total_images[n] = items[18].trim()` and replaced the title cell in the .csv with a number to no avail. I'm going to take a break and try to come back with fresh eyes later. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I created TagUI but I don't check Stack Overflow for user queries and issues. Try raising issue directly at GitHub next time - https://github.com/kelaberetiv/TagUI/issues

Looks like you found the solution! Yes, if the CSV file contains incorrect number of columns (some rows with more columns than others), it will lead to error when trying to work on it from your automation script. It looks like the extra commas cause extra columns and broke your code.